# failed to wrap stack navigator inside redux-provider in react-native

Tags: react-native

following is the code to wrap stack navigator inside a redux provider

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WelcomePage from './components/welcomePage';
import Register from './components/register';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Provider,connect } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/store';

const mapStateToProps=state => {
    return state;
}
const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

const handleSubmit=values=> {
  console.log(values);
}
const Navigationapp=StackNavigator({welcome:{screen:WelcomePage},register:{screen:props=><Register {...props} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}>}});
const Container = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Navigationapp);
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (<Provider store={store}>
                     <Container/>
            </Provider>)
    }
};
```

but it shows following error

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in C:\wamp64\www\rnativeTestProj\App.js: C:/wamp64/www/rnativeTestProj/App.js: Unexpected token, expected } (42:12)
  40 | const Container = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Navigationapp);
  41 | export default class App extends Component{
> 42 |     render(){
     |             ^
  43 |         return (<Provider store={store}>
  44 |                      <Container/>
  45 |             </Provider>)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

what am I missing?is it a correct way to wrap stack navigator inside a redux-provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen:props=><Register {...props} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

You lost a closing slash, it should be `<Register />`.